# How exclude jars when building Runnable Jar using Gradle Application Plugin DistZip Task

Tags: build-automation, gradle

When we use the Gradle Application plugin to create runnable jar for my project the distZip task adds all the jars that are not relevant to the lib folder.

Is there any way that I can exclude the jars that are not required in the distribution zip file that is created by Gradle.

Comment: When you say "not relevant" what exactly do you mean? Please provide your build script's `dependencies` block and annotate the ones you consider not to be relevant.

Comment: In th Dependencies I am adding compile 'org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:3.6.0'. When I do distZip it adds commons-httpclient-3.1, commons-logging-1.0.4, slf4j-api-1.6.1, solr-solrj-3.6.0, wstx-asl-3.2.7 jars in the lib folder. However, I need only solr jar to be present in the lib folder not the others when I do distZip

Comment: I know that the SolrJ client library uses HTTPClient under the covers. It's considered a transitive dependency and is required to work properly at runtime. Therefore, it's included in the distribution.

Comment: Is there any way that i can exclude the transitive dependency

Comment: I am not sure why you want to this in your case except if you'd have a version conflict but yes you can do it. The [Gradle user guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#exclude-dependencies) describes how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for the solution. I require this as this jar is customized to use http client from another evn home libs. Hence, I now used transitive = false for solr compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to exclude the transitive dependency jars in the dist added.

```
compile ("org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:3.6.0"){
            transitive = false
}
```